# Let $G$ be a nonabelian group. Let $a \in G$ have order $4$ and let $b \in G$ have order $3$. Then the order of the element $ab$ in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a nonabelian group. Let $a \in G$ have order $4$ and let $b \in G$ have order $3$. Then the order of the element $ab$ in $G$ :

A. is $6$.

B. is $12$

C. is of the form $12k, k \geq 2$

D. need not be finite'

> **Attempt:** I think the correct option should be $D.$ need not be finite. Since, $G$ is non abelian, A,B,C  shouldn't be true. I just am not able to find a suitable example for D.

Am I correct in my inference?

Thank you for your help in this regard.

Comment: May be you should search in GL(2,R) !

Comment: Yes D is correct. (I don't really understand why they specified that $G$ is nonabelian, because it does not affect the answer.)

Comment: @DerekHolt in abelian group as gcd(3,4)=1 therefore o(ab)=o(a)o(b) !

Comment: @DerekHolt The reasoning for Arpit Kansal's statement is quite easy: If $ord(x)=a$ and $ord(y)=b$, then $(xy)^{ab}=(x\cdot y)\cdot (x\cdot y)\cdot ....\cdot (x\cdot y)=x\cdot x \cdot x \cdot....\cdot x \cdot y \cdot y \cdot ... \cdot y =e\cdot e=e $ ,rearranging because $G$ is abelian, so $ord(xy)\leq ab$.

Comment: @ArpitKansal Yes, that's true, but so what? I said that leaving out the word "nonabelian" would not change the answer to the question, which is true!

Comment: @DerekHolt Did you mean that in abelian group too order of ab can be infinite?(Which is certainly not true)

Comment: @ArpitKansal The point is just that if the word "nonabelian" were deleted from the question the answer would still be D, because the group could nevertheless *be* nonabelian so the order of ab still need not be finite.

Comment: @aPaulT ohh i see..I was thinking that DerekHolt is talking about changing "nonabelian" to "abelian"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ (order $4$) and $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ (order $3$). and their product is $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 1& -1 \end{bmatrix}$ which is of infinite order.